# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment 'Cart' total calculation

Tags: javascript

```
function totalPrice()
        {
        var totalItems = document.getElementsByName("price").length;
        var total = 0;
        var rgx = /[^0-9]\x2e$/g;
        var price;
        var string_in = document.getElementsByName("price");

        for (var x=0; x<totalItems-1; x++){

            price = new Number(rgx.exec(string_in[x].text));
            parseFloat(total) = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(price); //This is where the error occurs
        }
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = ' $' + total;
        }
```

This is my function that the script executes, There are x number of items in my 'cart'. we must write this function in Javascript only. No php. The Named elements contain a price in the form of $123.45 (or more digits)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erm... just remove the `parseFloat()` from around the left-hand side.

Side-note: Always work in integers, especially when it comes to money. In this case, have your prices in cents on the code side. Only divide by 100 (or even just insert a decimal point via string functions) at the very end to display the result in dollars. This will avoid floating-point inaccuracies.

Comment: Okay, done. Now i get a number that i wasnt expecting. I think something else is wrong with the code. I'm not even close to knowing what i'm doing with regular expressions, I was trying to remove the $ from the prices and read the strings as numbers then add them to the running total. Am I close to doing so?

Comment: Probably because of your weird regex. Can't you just use `substr` like normal people? Can't you use number literals instead of `new Number` like normal people?

Comment: Let's start with normal people and replace that with I know you're a student but this is how I write it. I found something that looked like it could work, if they allowed the beginner/idiot tag then maybe that would help you understand.

anyway, I thought of using substr originally but i could wrap around it. thanks for the idea.

Comment: To fix the function i removed the regex and added this:
`for (var x=0; x<totalItems; x++){
    
    price = string_in[x].innerHTML.substr(1,string_in.length-1);
    total = parseInt(total) + parseInt(price);
   }`

Thanks @Kolink but remember something, not all of us are experts nor do we know proper coding techniques 100% of the time.